# Pulsar message acknowledge applies on topic or subscription?

Tags: apache-pulsar

I'm new to Pulsar and after reading some document I am a little bit confusing about message acknowledge.

Say, I have one topic, and two subscriptions: SubA and SubB. Now a message is consumed by SubA and SubB, but only SubA acknowledged that message. Now my question is, say after 2 days, our retention policy kicks in and it want to delete all *acknowledged* message older than 2 days, then in this case, is the message considered acknowledged or not? (because only SubA acknowledged it, SubB didn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is considered not acknowledged and will not be deleted. It is still being held for delivery in subscription SubB. Messages need to be acknowledged in *all* subscriptions before they are removed.

Like a traditional message broker, Pulsar keeps unacknowledged messages indefinitely. If this is not what you want, you can configure message TTL, which *acknowledges* a message after a configurable amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually went to your blog :). So if I don't acknowledge the message at all, then I use TTL instead of retention policy to manage the storage, that is also ok, right?